# QGIS 2.8.1-wien: how to unselect multiple layers from imported dxf?

Tags: query, dxf, qgis-2.8

I'm using the following syntax within the query builder in order to unselect a layer from a dxf added as a vector to the project:

```
'Layer' NOT  LIKE '15%'
```

It works but now I want to deselect some other layers e.g. '16%'

Now my question is why the following expression is not returning the correct result (just a selection of layers) but rather all possible layers of the dxf file?

```
'Layer' NOT  LIKE '15%' OR 'Layer' NOT  LIKE '16%'
```

Would any other syntax be possible for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `AND` instead of `OR`. If you want to deselect more layers you have to use AND. OR uses either 15% or 16%

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-logical.html

```
'Layer' NOT LIKE '15%' AND 'Layer' NOT LIKE '16%'
```